# Kafka Consumer Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 22 : {FINSRVC_TOPIC_PROD=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}

Tags: apache-kafka

my springboot kafka consumer microservice worked fine when I deployed it the first time in production, and consumed the messages.
I re-deployed the microservice last week with minor changes, then it started giving this warning.

`2022-07-10 03:30:02.653  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-finsrvc-consumer-group-1, groupId=finsrvc-consumer-group] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 22 : {FINSRVC_TOPIC_PROD=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

Changes were -

1: in Config file changed FixedBackOff from (5000L,3) to (2000L,2)

2: in dockerfile, added the following RUN command

`RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Additional Info:

1. There were no changes to Kafka brokers settings.
2. I am using Kafka version 3.2.0 and springboot version 2.6.2
3. Kafka cluster containing multiple brokers hosted in AWS but the microservice is hosted in google cloud.
4. While microservice is throwing the warning, fortunately it is also consuming the messages. Just concerned if any messages are being dropped.

Comment: Have you verified that your app in GCP can actually reach the brokers in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

This exception indicates that you are trying publish an event into a topic which doesn't exit. Can you set the value to **auto.create.topics.enable = true** and give it a try. Also, you may need to check the following properties were not overwritten with default after your upgrade.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ChristDist.   Topic name still exist as I confirmed it using kafka topic describe CLI command.   And also there were no changes to the Kafka broker properties.